# How to stop updating location when user presses logout button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, logout

I am developing a application in Swift using mapview and am fetching current location for every 3 minutes using nsstimer. I can able to fetch location and everything works fine.

Sample code in my mapview controller:In view didload method

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(180.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeToMoveOn), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func timeToMoveOn()
{
 print(latitude)

 print(longitude)

}
```

It helps to fetch current location for every 3 minutes

Sample code for logout action which written in another view controller:

```
  var viewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
  var appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as?
        AppDelegate)!
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewcontroller
    appDelegate.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

It also works fine and am able to return to login page, but the PROBLEM is when I tapped logout action that func `timeToMoveOn` is keep on updating current location I don't want to update location when the user tapped logout action. How to stop NSTimer?

I have searched other Stack Overflow answers and that does not support me because my nstimer and logout action are performing in different controllers. Can someone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: timer?.invalidate()  call logout time

Comment: where i have to include this code...and how to call logout time can you explain in brief...thanks for your quick response @jayesh miruliya

Answer (score 0):

Logout_Button Clicked_Event click time call that NSTimer method of other mapview controller :

```
var MapVC:mapviewcontrolle = mapviewcontrolle() // diffrent view controller object
MapVC.timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: timer shows me error....because am using different controllers i cant call timer...what to do??

Comment: create that controllers object.... and that access that timer object ...call that method

Comment: am trying that one but that shows me error as mapviewcontroller does not have timer....but that showing func timetomoveon...i dont know why this showing this error..i think it does not take because i declared timer in view did load mathod...am correct??